# SUDO successful for Active Directory admin group member using wrong password

Tags: sudo, freebsd, active-directory

Environment:

```
  OS: FreeBSD 12.1-Release-p10
  Sudo: 1.9.5p2
  Samba: 4.13.1_1
```

We've recently migrated to an Active Directory backend for DNS, DHCP, and in-house SSO support.  I have SSH logins working well, using PAM to authenticate via the Samba/Winbindd setup.  I want to control who can use sudo (just as root for now) via AD group memberships.

To that end, I created a new group in AD called "Unix Admins" that I would like sudo to check membership of, just like it does for local users and the wheel group.  To that end I simply duplicated the existing wheel entry and have two group check lines as follows:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
%Unix\ Admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

When an AD user who is not in either wheel or the new group logs in and tries to use sudo, they get the normal error about not being in the sudoers file, as expected.  When they *are* in the AD group but not wheel, they are prompted for their password, and if they enter their password correctly the command executes as expected.

However, when they enter the *wrong* password, they are shown an error message that is a little cryptic given the situation, and then the command executes anyway as if they entered the correct password.

The error happens as follows:

```
% sudo ls
Password:
When trying to update a password, this return status indicates that the value provided as the current password is not correct.
<<ls output here>>
```

Edit: Edited for clarity.

Edit2: /etc/pam.d & /usr/local/etc/pam.d relevant contents

**/usr/local/etc/pam.d/sudo**

```
#
# $FreeBSD: branches/2021Q1/security/sudo/files/pam.conf 340872 2014-01-24 00:14:07Z mat $
#
# PAM configuration for the "sudo" service
#

# auth
auth            include         system

# account
account         include         system

# session
# XXX: pam_lastlog (used in system) causes users to appear as though
# they are no longer logged in in system logs.
session         required        pam_permit.so

# password
password        include         system
```

**/etc/pam.d/system**

```
#
# $FreeBSD: releng/12.1/lib/libpam/pam.d/system 197769 2009-10-05 09:28:54Z des $
#
# System-wide defaults
#

# auth
auth            sufficient      pam_opie.so             no_warn no_fake_prompts
auth            requisite       pam_opieaccess.so       no_warn allow_local
#auth           sufficient      pam_krb5.so             no_warn try_first_pass
#auth           sufficient      pam_ssh.so              no_warn try_first_pass
auth            sufficient      pam_unix.so             no_warn try_first_pass nullok
auth            sufficient      pam_winbind.so          try_first_pass

# account
#account        required        pam_krb5.so
account         required        pam_login_access.so
account         required        pam_unix.so

# session
#session        optional        pam_ssh.so              want_agent
session         required        pam_lastlog.so          no_fail

# password
#password       sufficient      pam_krb5.so             no_warn try_first_pass
password        required        pam_unix.so             no_warn try_first_pass
```

Comment: FreeBSD uses PAM doesn't it? Please post the contents of `/etc/pam.d/sudo ` and any files that it includes by reference

Comment: Done deal @roaima sorry for not putting them in the original message.  The sudo PAM file is straight from the factory, the system file was modified to include pam_winbind, and to change the pam_unix module from required to sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PAM modules in FreeBSD do not work like the ones in Linux as we had thought, and do in fact function as documented.

The problem lied in the preceeding modules in the auth section, regarding the OPIE system.  Those modules are active by default and always succeed for users who do not initialize OPIE in their accounts -- which honestly, is basically everyone.  That resulted in a passing auth subsection even when all "normal" auth modules returned failure, if those modules were set to "sufficient" or "optional".

The solution was to remove the lines referencing the two OPIE modules.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your problem, "*the system file was modified to include `pam_winbind`, and to change the `pam_unix` module from `required` to `sufficient`*".

It would be well worth taking the time to read [chapter 4.1](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration-file.html) of the [Linux PAM Administrators' Guide](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html) (yes, I know you're on FreeBSD), so that you can understand the detail of what I explain here.

When you had `pam_unix` set to `required`, it immediately returned *success* or *failure* depending on the validity of the password. When you changed it to `sufficient` it only returned *success* but otherwise continued on. *There was now no failure mode*.

Your `auth` stack can now return *success* or the default value, which happens to be *success*. To fix the problem, add a `deny` as the last stack entry for `auth`

```
# auth
auth            sufficient      pam_opie.so             no_warn no_fake_prompts
auth            requisite       pam_opieaccess.so       no_warn allow_local
auth            sufficient      pam_unix.so             no_warn try_first_pass nullok
auth            sufficient      pam_winbind.so          try_first_pass
auth            required        pam_warn.so
auth            required        pam_deny.so
```

Comment the `pam_warn` entry if you don't want PAM to log authentication failures.

---

Useful keywords for PAM stacks

- `required` - failure will ultimately lead to the stack returning *failure*, but only after the remaining modules have been executed
- `requisite` - *failure* will be returned immediately
- `sufficient` - *success* will be returned immediately, unless a *failure* from `required` is already pending

Comment: That makes a ton of sense.  I had no idea that the default would be to succeed rather than fail in the event that none of the modules resulted in success.

Comment: Had a chance to investigate this today, and this is not the whole story unfortunately.  While the man page says that processing stops at "sufficient" if it succeeds that doesn't seem to actually be the case, as adding a pam_deny after the two sufficient entries as you indicated causes all logins to fail, nevermind sudo..

Comment: @alzee I'll set up some tests locally too (Linux not FreeBSD)

Comment: Cool.  Here's the documentation from the FreeBSD pam.d man page regarding "sufficient" which indicates to me it shouldn't need the following pam_deny...

<<sufficient>>    If this module succeeds, the chain is broken and the result
                   is success.  If it fails, the rest of the chain still runs,
                   but the final result will be failure unless a later module
                   succeeds.

Comment: There's obviously more to it than I understand here.  Removing pam_winbind and just changing the pam_unix lines to "sufficient" from "required" allows any login to succeed regardless of the password supplied being correct.  If "sufficient" is working as intended, it means pam_unix is returning success in cases where I presumed it would fail, such as with an incorrect password.

Comment: @alzee with `pam_unix` set to `sufficient` then if pam_unix succeeds it returns that success immediately, otherwise the stack continues unaffected. Eventually you fall off the end of the stack and your authentication is considered to have succeeded. If you're going to return immediately with `sufficient` you must have something on the end of the stack that fails, i.e. `required pam_deny`

Comment: that is the opposite of what the man page states.  I quoted it above but it says that the chain exits immediately if the "sufficient" module succeeds, otherwise it continues evaluating other modules and will **fail** if none of them succeed.  The FreeBSD man page for pam.d is here : https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pam.d&sektion=5&n=1

My confusing experience so far is this:
1. Any number of "sufficient" modules followed by pam_deny *always* denies.
2. Any number of "sufficient" modules followed by nothing will succeed.
3. Only "required" works as intended.

Comment: I thought I'd come back and post my own answer, and let you know with an update.  The issue was the two OPIE modules in my original question.  They (well at least one of them) succeed even when the user hasn't set an OPIE password, causing the AUTH section to succeed even when all the passwords are wrong and the other modules are set to "sufficient."  Just removing them fixed the issue -- and the default is to fail, not succeed, as the FreeBSD documentation indicates.

Comment: Thank you for that update @alzee